# Insert Cell data in one row ( from A1 to An )

Tags: excel, sorting

i have been try to solved this using tutorial from google ( everywhere ) but i'm not find any answer, i hope i can  found the answer here.

here is my data

```
       A        B     C
     +-------+----+-----+
  1  |  123  |  4 |  5  |
  2  |  678  |  9 | 10  |
     +-------+----+-----+
```

the result that i need :

```
         A     B     C
     +-------+----+-----+
  1  |  123  |    |     |
  2  |  678  |    |     |
  3  |   4   |    |     |
  4  |   5   |    |     |
  5  |   9   |    |     |
  6  |  10   |    |     |
     +-------+----+-----+
```

or in other order like :

```
123 
  4
  5
678
...
```

any one know how to solved this ?

Comment: For your last part you could use a helper column that takes the first number of the value using the LEFT formula and then sorting.

Comment: For the first part you need to determine the amount of columns used. Then copy a row and do secial paste and transpose. Then your next row needs to start at the row that is equal to the amount of columns in the original dataset.

Comment: @Luuklag : thank you for your reply ..... i have try transpos before and after your reply .... the result  is not correct , it just change row and col ...
<br>i mean, how to make it all data ( sometime it will have until zz100 ) in one col ( A )

Comment: Your solution is called VBA. See the tag `[excel-vba]`

Comment: i think vba will solved it.... i will learn more about it thank you @Luuklag